# Printing Internal Tex variables to log file

Tags: tex-core, debugging

Consider the MWE below. I created this based on: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-printvar.html . What I intend to do here is print the value of an internal variable (`totalleftmargin`) to log (or the document itself) in mm.

The snippet below does not compile. If I change to `\message{\the\@totalleftmargin}` I get as output 2 times: `1000\@m {}totalleftmargin` which is not an actual value (or is that 1000, but then it is not increasing)??

I expect this value to be increased (because we are indented). How can I output internal tex variables?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{mm}
\begin{document}
Test \message{Normal totalleftmargin is:} \printlength{\@totalleftmargin}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test2 \message{In this list the totalleftmargin is:} \printlength{\@totalleftmargin}
\end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is the `@` character in variable name, which is "special" for latex. If you surround you use `\makeatletter\printlength{\@totalleftmargin}\makeatother` it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\@totalleftmargin` has `@` in its name, thus `\makatletter` helps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{mm}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
Test \message{Normal totalleftmargin is:} \printlength{\@totalleftmargin}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test2 \message{In this list the totalleftmargin is:} \printlength{\@totall
\end{itemize}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Expandable solution for `\message` or `\typeout`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\printlength}[1]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr2.54\dimexpr(#1)/72\relax\relax\space mm%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
Test \typeout{Normal totalleftmargin is: \printlength{\@totalleftmargin}}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test2
  \typeout{In this list the totalleftmargin is:
  \printlength{\@totalleftmargin}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Result in the console and `.log` file:

```
Normal totalleftmargin is: 0 mm
...
In this list the totalleftmargin is: 0.88196 mm
```

(The values differ, because the typeset content is different.)